# Do we have any css and html extensions for django framework?

Tags: html, django, django-templates, haml, sass

I have spent some time in `django`, but templating seems to be:

- Non-productive
- Time consuming
- Difficult to manage the spaghetti code [ Django tags + HTML ]

I looked around for alternative and found:

- SASS [ CSS extension ]      -- For rails
- SLIM [ HTML extension ]

But I found non of the above specifically talking of `django`, neither did I found any of the above on the official `django` documentation.

**So, Do we have any css / html extensions for django ?**

**Is it preffered to use these with django ?**

Please talk about these in reference to django. **[ Any guidance is appreciated ]**

Comment: One was finally added FYI https://github.com/avanov/Plim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you will not find any references to these in the official django documentation is because these are not bundled with the official django release. In addition, and more importantly - django (and python in general) doesn't endorse any particular third party library as the next great Special Sauce to be used.  If there is some third party component that does something particularly well - django will integrate it (as was the case with `django-staticfiles` which became part of the official django release).

You will find community recommendations though. For example `lxml` is widely praised for xml/html parsing, however it is not officially endorsed in the Python documentation.

Similarly with django they don't endorse third party software to be used. Instead, they let you decide what fits your brain the best, which I prefer.

If you must, you can:

- Use SASS with django via [`django_compressor`](http://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings/#backend-settings)
- Use HAML with django by first installing [`HamlPy`](https://github.com/jessemiller/HamlPy) and then [`djaml`](https://github.com/chartjes/djaml) / [`Djinja`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Djinja) / [`django-haml`](https://github.com/fitoria/django-haml) (or use the bundled hamlpy-watcher script which is similar to SASS's watcher)

SLIM seems to be a template engine for Ruby. If you are looking for alternates (again, I wouldn't recommend this for sake of compatibility with other applications), you can use [`jinja2`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/) with django.

Keep in mind that django is a full stack framework, so everything is included in the box and is tightly integrated to get you running off the ground quickly. If you prefer a more "bring your own component" approach, you should explore other frameworks. The most pluggable one is [`Pyramid`](http://www.pylonsproject.org/) which evolved from the excellent `Pylons` project.

Comment: I got your point, why is it not talked about on django official page.
But are there any django focused extensions for HTML , CSS, etc like we have for rails ?

Comment: You mean other than the two I mentioned?

Comment: Yup, I want to realize a ready environment for what's available for rails and if not then what is keeping django from that ?

Comment: Rails and Django are two very different approaches to the same problem. I doubt you'll find equivalent for all that comes with Rails in Django. Don't try to do "rails" in django, and don't try to do "django" in rails.

Comment: I will say, yes they are approaching differently, but what about solving the same problems in django - Abstracting HTML and CSS in django templates ?

Comment: You have already given an informative answer, I am looking for something more in-depth. Searching..

Comment: @YugalJindle I'm confused. Will HAML not abstract HTML in your templates? He gave advice on getting HAML to work with Django.

Comment: @Paragon Sir, I know about HAML already, but before starting off - I am looking for what is presently most used solutions. HAML was there but not much talked about in the django world. I am sincerely looking around how and what people are looking, It might turn out to be HAML itself.

Comment: @YugalJindle I understand. However, the reason your question has a downvote is because it's too vague for us to answer, and because we clearly had no idea what you were after. Please keep this in ind in the future. You also told Burhan that his answer was informative, but did not give him an upvote. It is polite to do so.

Comment: Respect you sir, I didn't upvoted since I didn't felt it like what I was looking for. He answered what I can Google, though aggregated stuff. I am looking for a more of an experienced advise.

Comment: @YugalJindle - from my experience, specifically of `django`, the moment you try to plug in your own stuff (like the ORM, or templates engines) you start losing the benefit of it; which is why you do not see many "choices" when it comes to the various components of django. This is also why I suggested Pyramid in my answer as it is more open and pluggable.

Comment: Great.. It seems its been a bull run to down-vote.

Answer (score 0):

[Check out Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/). I have to admit that I know absolutely nothing about it. Nevertheless, there is a [Quora question](http://www.quora.com/What-is-a-good-templating-engine-for-Python) with a couple of answers worth reading. Other examples found there are [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/) and [Cheetah](http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/).

ParagonRG

Comment: Hey, if you closely compare: this is not an answer to my question. Jinja2, etc are more of alternatives to templating - I am asking for extensions to specifically html, css !

Comment: Although Cheetah, Mako seem to be close to the question but in a different respect.

Comment: I guess I figured I would try to get at the root of your problem, which was that templating is a pain in the ass. So I suggested other templating systems. Besides, HAML is a templating language.

Comment: Okay.. I am looking into it.. I might be having a wrong impression in my mind.

Comment: taking haml away from the question !